# On live boot USBs, where is the required filesystem label configured?

Tags: boot-loader, live-usb

I could probably find this on google if I knew the verbiage to search for.
When booting a live USB, the bootloader always (at least for the distros I've used) looks for a filesystem with specific label. I'm wanting to know where to find this so that

1. I could set the label and extract the ISO without having to use Rufus or Etcher and
2. So that maybe I can modify this and have multiple distros install from the same USB

Comment: UEFI does not use label. It expects an ESP - efi system partition with boot,esp flags that actually is a very long GUID/partUUID. Use gpt partitioning.  For Ubuntu you can just create a 6GB ESP and extract ISO. It then boots from UEFI boot menu of flash drive using /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi which is used for all external devices and fallback on internal devices. Will not work in BIOS mode. Installers add BIOS boot to MBR which is not required for UEFI. I prefer a full install with only a few repair tools added & then loopmount ISOs with grub2.

Comment: I believe what I'm looking for is inside initrd. I extracted the EFI files plus OS specific files. During startup, the OS looks for either an image to extract or a folder with OS files to run from. Most distros (that I've tested) do this step by looking for a filesystem with a label. I think this is happening inside initrd so I think I have to decompile/extract, modify, and recompile. Alternatively, I could get the source and compile with my own options.

To answer my own question, I think the easiest way to get the label I'm looking for is to get the isofs label of the downloaded ISO.

Comment: It really cannot just be a label as I have multiple installs. Grub uses UUID to boot each install.

Comment: You're probably talking about post-install and that makes sense for an install. I'm talking about the live usb or installer usb. For example, to use PopOS installer USB, I must use Rufus or Etcher to write it to a USB. If I extract the ISO contents to a USB, it will show the boot menu and will attempt to boot but during the boot process, it searches for a filesystem label. If it doesn't find it, then it fails to mount /

Comment: Boot ISO and then open terminal and see all the mount points. I regularly run mount command part way thru install to unmount the ESP & mount the ESP I want Ubuntu to install grub into. Bug in Ubiquity that only mounts first drive's ESP. Not sure about other distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my original question is that it's specified inside initrd. If I want to simply get the label and apply it to a filesystem, then I can either mount the ISO or use any utility that shows the isofs label. If I want to modify it then I need to decompile/recompile the initrd or compile the live/installer USB from source